# How to create Tkinter Widgets inside Parent class from Sub class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The first example creates the post titles in his parent which works(except it doesn't delete the old titles when I search new ones), but because imo it looks super messy I wanted to split the class into 2.
 One in which the checkbutton is, which expands the first frame with the second and in which the `post.titles labels` should be created. In the second Frame(which expands the 1.frame)
are 2 labels which describe the entry fields, the 2 entries and the search button. This button calls the `advanced_search` function in my StackoverflowApi and returns a list of `post` objects. This is list is needed in the `createPosts` function in my first class.

The porblem is in my second example the posts get created in the second Frame not in the first.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpQfN.jpg) is an example how it should look and how it does look right now

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import StackoverflowApi as API

class SearchFrame:
    def __init__(self, parent, title, main_frame):
        self.main_frame=main_frame
        self.title=title
        self.parent=parent
        self.expanded = tk.IntVar()
        self.expanded.set(0)
        self.pagesize=tk.IntVar()
        self.pagesize.set(10)
        self.tags=tk.StringVar()

        self.title_frame=ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.title_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)

        self.expand_button=ttk.Checkbutton(self.title_frame,
                                           text=self.title +' +',
                                           command=self.expand,
                                           variable=self.expanded,
                                           style='Toolbutton',
                                           )
        self.expand_button.pack(fill='x', expand=1)
        #self.expand_button.configure(bg='grey') gonna fix this later

        self.sub_frame=ttk.Frame(self.parent, relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)

        self.tag_label=ttk.Label(self.sub_frame,
                                 text='Tags').pack(side='left',
                                                   expand=1,
                                                   pady=5)
        self.tag_entry=ttk.Entry(self.sub_frame,
                                 textvariable=self.tags).pack(side='left',
                                                              expand=1,
                                                              pady=5)
        self.pagesize_label=ttk.Label(self.sub_frame,
                                      text='Pagesize').pack(side='left',
                                                            expand=1,
                                                            pady=5)
        self.pagesize_entry=ttk.Entry(self.sub_frame,
                                      textvariable=self.pagesize).pack(side='left',
                                                                       expand=1,
                                                                       pady=5)
        self.search_button=ttk.Button(self.sub_frame, text='Search',
                                      command=self.search).pack(side='left',
                                                                expand=1,
                                                                pady=5)

    def search(self):
        api = API.StackoverflowApi()
        self.posts = api.advanced_search(tagged=list(self.tags.get()),
                                    pagesize=self.pagesize.get())

        for post in self.posts:
            self.post=ttk.Label(self.parent, text=post.title).pack()

    def expand(self):
        if bool(self.expanded.get()):
            self.sub_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)
            self.expand_button.configure(text=self.title +' -')
        else:
            self.sub_frame.forget()
            self.expand_button.configure(text=self.title +' +')

root = tk.Tk()
search = SearchFrame(root,'Search Options')
search.search()
root.mainloop()
```

This is was my attempt to do the above code splitted in two classes because i think it looks messy

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import StackoverflowApi as API

root=Tk()
class FrameOne(ttk.Frame):
    ''' Main Frame in which posts should be created '''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack()

        #Vars
        self.expanded=IntVar()
        self.expanded.set(0)

        self.expand_button=ttk.Checkbutton(self,
                                           text='Seach Options +',
                                           command=self.expand,
                                           variable=self.expanded,
                                           style='Toolbutton',
                                           )
        self.expand_button.pack(fill='x', expand=1)

        self.sub_frame=ExtendingFrame(parent, relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)


    def expand(self):#function for expanding the second frame
        if bool(self.expanded.get()):
            self.sub_frame.pack(fill="x", expand=1)
            self.expand_button.configure(text='Seach Options -')
        else:
            self.sub_frame.forget()
            self.expand_button.configure(text='Seach Options +')

    def createPosts(self, posts):

        for post in posts:
            self.post=ttk.Label(self, text=post.title)
            self.post.pack()


class ExtendingFrame(FrameOne):
    ''' this is the frame, which apperas when the checkbutton in the first frame
    is clicked.
    The Frame has 2 entries "tags" and "pagesize" I need these for my api call
     '''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent=parent
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        #Vars
        self.tags=StringVar()
        self.pagesize=IntVar()
        self.pagesize.set(15)

        self.tag_label=ttk.Label(self, text='Tags', anchor='e')
        self.tag_label.pack(fill='x', expand=1, side='left', pady=5, padx=2)
        self.tag_entry=ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.tags)
        self.tag_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=1, side='left', pady=5)
        self.pagesize_label=ttk.Label(self, text='Pagesize', anchor='e')
        self.pagesize_label.pack(fill='x', expand=1,side='left', pady=5, padx=2)
        self.pagesize_entry=ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.pagesize)
        self.pagesize_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=1, side='left', pady=5)
        self.search_button=ttk.Button(self, text='Search',command=self.search)
        self.search_button.pack(fill='x', expand=1, side='left', pady=5, padx=2)

    def search(self):
        ''' calls the search function of the api, with the '''
        api = API.StackoverflowApi()
        self.posts = api.advanced_search(
                tagged=list(self.tags.get()),
                pagesize=self.pagesize.get()
                 )
        #self.posts is a list of question objects returned by the api
        return super().createPosts(self.posts)#I need the objects from the list in my createPosts function

main=FrameOne(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you want the widgets to go into the parent? If you're doing that, what's the point of using the class? I don't think I've ever seen a good use case for a class that inherits from a frame that creates widgets outside of itself. You eliminate all benefits of the class inheriting from `Frame`.

Comment: This is simply not how inheritance works. You can't expect an object to create a subobject that inherits from itself to work reliably. You also can't expect any tkinter code to work after `mainloop()` exits. By definition, it won't exit until the widgets have all been destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley In my real code the second frame is expandable so it has some functions i don't need in my main class. The secondframe also has 2 Entries and a button which calls a function like `labels`. Should I define all these things in main?(I did it before and tought it looked pretty messy)

Comment: I don't think you need a subclass for this, but you could rather use another class that works the way you want. Also right now your question is more complex. You can have two frame classes that have their children etc. and you can call one inside the other without having to inherit from a base class.

Comment: @Nae So you mean i don't need to inhert from `FrameOne`? But how would I call `createPosts` then, if I would use `FrameOne(self.parent).createPosts(self.posts)` it would create a new Instance of the Frame and I would have two checkbuttons(I tried this before)

Comment: @MushroomMauLa The same way we can call tkinter methods. your `createPosts` has no dependency to your `FrameOne` but rather dependency on tkinter. So you should be able to use that method given that it is defined for your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Below code has two classes, `MainApp` to structure outermost frame of our app, and then `SearchFrame` class that uses a method from `MainApp` to create a label in its parent widget. In this case `SearchFrame`'s parent widget is `MainApp`. You can comment out geometry manager to `self.frame2` if you want to see that the label is in fact created inside the parent widget subclass `MainApp`. Again, I doubt that this is good practice:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        #a child frame of MainApp object
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)

        tk.Label(self.frame1, text="This is MainApp frame1").pack()

        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        #another child frame of MainApp object
        self.frame2 = SearchFrame(self)

        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")




    def create_labels(self, master):
        return tk.Label(master, text="asd")


class SearchFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="this is SearchFrame")
        self.label.pack()

        master.label1 = MainApp.create_labels(self, master)

        master.label1.grid()


mainAppObject = MainApp(root)
mainAppObject.pack()

root.mainloop()
```