# Using classes as frames in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm currently working on a Python Tkinter code which is getting longer and longer. I wanted to implement using multiple classes for some of the frames in my GUI.

Below code is a sample of what I am trying to do. Basically making a class which has a frame, and the frame is using another class as a parent.

But when I run the code, I get this error "'MainProgram' object has no attribute 'FirstFrame'"

Any solutions? I tried searching but I wasn't successful on finding something like this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainwin = tk.Tk()
        self.FirstFrame()        


class FirstFrame():
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstframe = ttk.LabelFrame(self.MainProgram.mainwin, text="hi")
        self.firstframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainProgram()
    main.mainwin.mainloop
```

Comment: FirstFrame is not a method of your class MainProgram, that's why you are getting that error.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360640/how-to-create-tkinter-widgets-inside-parent-class-from-sub-class

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
self.Firstframe()
```

With:

```
self.ff=Firstframe()
```

- `Firstframe()` is not an attribute of `Mainprogram`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the link here for a good starting point for code organization into classes

[Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

the example can be used 'as is' for an organizational strategy or as a very good template to modify a piece at a time and learn of other possible structures where one class can be used to create instances of another.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainwin = tk.Tk()
        self.my_frame = FirstFrame()
        # examine the child parent relationship
        for child in self.mainwin.winfo_children():
            print(child['text'])        


class FirstFrame():
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstframe = ttk.LabelFrame(text="hi")
        self.firstframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
        ttk.Label(master=self.firstframe,text='a widget inside frame').grid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = MainProgram()
    main.mainwin.mainloop
```

Comment: Thank you! If I want to make the frame in the second class a child of the mainwin, I get an error. How would I be able to fix that? This is the error: "type object 'MainProgram' has no attribute 'mainwin'"

Comment: The parent child relationship of widgets can be examined with .winfo_children() method. The example above shows the frame in   MainProgram has a child with text=hi. Which seems to be what you are aiming at. It is an example of the changes required to make your original code work.

Comment: If I want to have FirstFrame.firstframe to be a child of MainProgram.win, I just can't make it work. In the code you provided, they are also not arranged to show how this would work. Can you help with this, please?