# How to create a Frame/Canvas using class in Python and use it many times with different widgets inside it?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, subclass

I am new in Python. I am developing a program which actually is a small shell for phpMyAdmin. In my program I need in some Windows (which is created by TKinter) draw a scrolled canvas. I've written a class like this to create a Scrolled Canvas. It's working great when I use it in every where  but problem is I need different widgets(Like: Buttons/ Labels/ Entry/ Combo-box, ... ) inside it in every Windows. I looked over the net and found a solution ([How to create Tkinter Widgets inside Parent class from Sub class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360640/how-to-create-tkinter-widgets-inside-parent-class-from-sub-class)) but that one makes my program so complicated. So I'm looking for a better solution that keeps my code simple.  Here is my Class which create Scrolled Form/Canvas:

```
class ScrolledCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master_frame, back_color, label_frame_text, border, x, y, w, h):
        super(ScrolledCanvas, self).__init__()
        dynamic_widget_frame = LabelFrame(master_frame, relief=SUNKEN, bg=back_color,
                                          text=label_frame_text, bd=border)
        dynamic_widget_frame.place(x=x, y=y)
        mycanvas = Canvas(dynamic_widget_frame, width=w, height=h)
        mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT)
        yscollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(dynamic_widget_frame, orient='vertical', command=mycanvas.yview)
        yscollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')
        mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscollbar.set)
        myframe = Frame(mycanvas)
        mycanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=myframe, anchor="nw")
        mycanvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda es: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox('all')))
        close_btn = Button(myframe, text='X', command=dynamic_widget_frame.destroy, fg='red')
        close_btn.grid()
```

This sample code explains how we can create a widget inside a class from outside it. But makes my code extremely long and complicated. Because I've multi different widgets in Windows.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        #a child frame of MainApp object
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)

        tk.Label(self.frame1, text="This is MainApp frame1").pack()

        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        #another child frame of MainApp object
        self.frame2 = SearchFrame(self)

        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")




    def create_labels(self, master):
        return tk.Label(master, text="asd")


class SearchFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="this is SearchFrame")
        self.label.pack()

        master.label1 = MainApp.create_labels(self, master)

        master.label1.grid()


mainAppObject = MainApp(root)
mainAppObject.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the point of `ScrolledCanvas` inheriting from `tk.Frame` because all widgets created inside `ScrolledCanvas.__init__()` are not children of it?

Comment: Exactly, Not all widgets are built inside canvas. The only widget inside canvas is a button to close the frame. In every where I use ScrolledCanvas Class, widgets are different. I don't know how create different widgets inside a same class.

Comment: I am not talking about the canvas inside `ScrolledCanvas`.  I am talking about `ScrolledCanvas` itself which is a frame.  No widget is created inside `ScrolledCanvas`.  Widgets are created inside *parent* of `ScrolledCanvas`.  Also `ScrolledCanvas` is created inside *root* window no matters what `master_frame` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're not creating the class correctly. You aren't passing `master` when you call `super().__init__`, and then you're explicitly putting the child widgets in the master.

The proper way to create a class that behaves like a widget is to pass the master to `super.__init__`, and then make sure every child widget is a child of the instance or a descendant of the widget.

```
class ScrolledCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master_frame, ...):
        super().__init__(master_frame)

        dynamic_widget_frame = LabelFrame(self, ...)

        ...
```

Next, make sure that `my_frame` is an instance attribute so that it can be referenced outside of the class. I would also give it a slightly better name:

```
class ScrolledCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master_frame, ...):
        ...
        self.frame = tk.Frame(mycanvas)
        mycanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")
        ...
```

Once you do these two things, you can create as many instances as you want and put them anywhere in your UI. You can then add additional widgets to the `frame` attribute of the object.

```
# create a scrolled canvas in the root
root = tk.Tk()
sc1 = ScrolledCanvas(root, ...)
sc1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# add widgets to this scrolled frame
label1 = tk.Label(sc1.frame, text="I am in the first window")
label1.pack(side="top")

# create another scrolled frame in a popup window
popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
sc2 = ScrolledCanvas(popup, ...)
sc2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# add widgets to this second scrolled frame
label2 = tk.Label(sc2.frame, text="This is in the popup")
label2.pack(side="top")
```

One last step is to be sure to bind to the `<Configure>` event of the inner frame so that you can reconfigure the `scrollregion` when the frame changes size.

```
class ScrolledCanvas(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master_frame, ...):
        ...
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all"))
        ...
```

Comment: I would suggest that `ScrolledCanvas` inherits from `tk.LabelFrame` directly to replace `dynamic_widget_frame`.